# Get JTable Integer cell values with cell formatting

Tags: java, swing, jtable, number-formatting

I have a JTable with a column containing integer values which are formatted to add a thousands separator.
I am able to get the value of the columns using `model.getValueAt()` or `table.getValueAt()` but the values don't have the formatting. How can I get the cell value with the formatting?

Code to format the cell:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(new NumberTableCellRenderer());
```

Code for the class which handles the cell formatting:

```
public static class NumberTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof Number) {
           value = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(value);
        
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }

}
```

Comment: *"the values don't have the formatting"* Only visual representations of numbers should have formatting. Format the number as it's being displayed elsewhere, but internally retain the integer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). It should be solved using an entirely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the cell value with the formatting?

You would need to reapply the rendering logic. Something like:

```
TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
Component c = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

if (c instanceof JLabel)
{
    JLabel label = (JLabel)c;
    String formatted = label.getText();
}
```

However, this will only get you the String value. It will not get any color rendering since a String does not contain information like that.